# Did Jesus abolish tithing in the temple when He overthrew the money changer's tables?

Tags: law, tithes

And Jesus went into the temple of God, and cast out all them that sold and bought in the temple, and overthrew the tables of the moneychangers, and the seats of them that sold doves
Matthew 21:12

Is this symbolic of the end of the Old Covenant and the start of the New Covenant?

It marks the end of sacrifices, but does it also mark the end of tithing?

He put a stop to selling animals but He also put a stop to money exchange necessary for tithing in the temple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q: Did Jesus abolish tithing in the temple when He overthrew the money changer's tables**

**NO HE DID NOT ABOLISH TITHING.**

God gave to the nation of Israel the Mosaic law regarding  ceremonies with clean and unclean meats , drinks , rules and regulations for cleansing of the body,TITHING  and other legal requirements until the appointed time.Paul wrote:

Hebrews 9:10  (NLT)

> 10 "For that old system deals only with food and drink and various
>   cleansing ceremonies—physical regulations that were in effect only
>   until a better system could be established."

Other translations render,"until a better system could be established."such as "until the time of reformation" and "until the time of new order." or "better covenant."

The scriptures say that all the  requirements of  the Mosaic Law which included tithing came to an end , completely wiped out, blotted , when Jesus was nailed to the cross. Paul wrote :

**Christ is the end of the Law.**

Romans 10:4 (NASB)

> "For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to everyone who
>   believes." "The Law nailed to the cross."

Colossians 2:13-14 (NASB)

> 13 "When you were dead [a]in your transgressions and the
>   uncircumcision of your flesh, He made you alive together with Him,
>   having forgiven us all our transgressions, 14 having canceled out the
>   certificate of debt consisting of decrees against us, which was
>   hostile to us; and He has taken it out of the way, having nailed it to
>   the cross."

**Adoption as sons of God.**

Galatians 4:4-5  (NASB)

> 4 "But when the fullness of the time came, God sent forth His Son,
>   born of a woman, born under the Law, 5 so that He might redeem those
>   who were under the Law, that we might receive the adoption as sons."

**The Law was a tutor to the Israelites to accept Jesus as the Messiah.**

Galatians 3:24-25 (NASB)

> " Therefore the Law has become our tutor to lead us to Christ, so that
>   we may be justified by faith. 25 But now that faith has come, we are
>   no longer under a tutor."

Comment: I believe you have done a good job of proving that tithes were abolished

Comment: I’m sorry but did you skip over the second paragraph? *NO HE DID NOT ABOLISH TITHING.*

Comment: Noted, have added "cleansing of" the body.

Comment: @OzzieNicolas in light of *“But now we are released from the law, having died to that which held us captive, so that we serve in the new way of the Spirit and not in the old way of the written code.”
‭‭Romans‬ ‭7:6‬* what is the new way of the Spirit to tithe? Especially since Christ did not come to abolish the law but to fulfill it. *“Therefore whoever relaxes one of the least of these commandments and teaches others to do the same will be called least in the kingdom of heaven, but whoever does them and teaches them will be called great in the kingdom of heaven.”
‭‭Matthew 5:19*

Comment: I'm sorry but didn't the law state that the tithe was to be given only to the Levites? Numbers 18:21
"To the sons of Levi, behold, I have given all the tithe in Israel for an inheritance, in return for their service which they perform, the service of the tent of meeting."

Comment: @DanLick, Do not be sorry to ask questions.  Yes,the Mosaic require a tenth (giving tithing)of the produce and a tenth increase of the herds be given to the Levites yearly to support them. The Levites in turn gave  a tenth of this tenth to support the priesthood. The Levites had no inheritance and were entirely devoted to the service of the sanctuary . Deut. 26:12 Hope this has answered your query.

Comment: @OzzieNicolas The "decrees against us" was not the Torah but rather the "charges". This is a reference to the Roman practice of nailing the charges against a condemned man above their head when they "staked" them. They nailed our charges on his "stake".

Answer (score 2):

[Very nice question]

He was doing three things: Abolishing the fact that animal sacrifice is no longer needed, that the house of God is a place of worship not a place of commerce and that all may come freely to receive forgiveness. No more barriers of entry.

In those times, they used to generate revenue by exchanging currency for temple coins, which were then used to buy sacrificial animals and to pay tithes. Within the temple the only valid currency was "temple coin".

And in case you were wondering:

> Malachi 3:10 (KJV)
>   Bring ye all the tithes into the storehouse, that there may be meat in mine house, and **prove me now herewith**, saith the Lord of hosts, if I will not open you the windows of heaven, and pour you out a blessing, that there shall not be room enough to receive it.

God does not change. Anything God said in the old testament is still valid in the new testament.

Comment: As I understand it, Malachi 3:10 was referring to the priests who were stealing the tithes and renting out the empty warehouses to Gentiles.

Comment: @Dan Lick, where does it say the Priests were stealing?

Comment: Malachi 2  “And now, O priests, this commandment is for you.+ 2  If you refuse to listen and to take it to heart to glorify my name,” says Jehovah of armies, “I will send on you the curse,+ and I will turn your blessings into curses.+ Yes, I have turned the blessings into curses, because you are not taking it to heart.”

Comment: Malachi 3:8  “Will a mere human rob God? But you are robbing me.”
And you say: “How have we robbed you?”
“In the tithes* and in the contributions. 9  You are certainly cursed,* for you are robbing me—yes, the entire nation is doing so. 10  Bring the entire tithe* into the storehouse,+ so that there may be food in my house;+ and test me out, please, in this regard,”

Answer (score 2):

Tithing was a command of the Old covenant, Christ fulfilled the righteousness of the law, and is the end of the law of righteousness to everyone that believes. Those that are "in Christ" or born again are not under such demands.

The new covenant encourages giving joyfully willfully, not of necessity, but out of a ready mind. The overthrowing of the tables was simply fulfillment of old testament prophecy, and shows God's additude towards making church a "house of merchandise".

Answer (score 1):

Jesus' purpose in overturning the tables in the temple was explicitly stated in Matt 21:13

> "It is written," he said to them, "'My house will be called a house of
>   prayer,' but you are making it 'a den of robbers.'"

This is nothing to do with either the ceremonial system nor tithing.  It has everything to do with respect for sacred places such as a temple dedicated to the worship and service of the Almighty God.  Jesus wanted to stop the desecration of the temple courts being used as a market by money changers and traders charging exorbitant fees for sacrifices - at complete odds with the free gift of grace at the heart of Jesus' teaching.

Indeed, when Jesus sent out his first missionaries, he told them, "Freely you have received; freely give" (Matt 10:8); quite the opposite of what was happening in the temple courts.

Comment: That was my original impression also but my pastor called my attention to the broader implications of Jesus's actions at the temple.

Comment: What did your pastor base his views upon in the text?  Jesus said nothing about this.  In fact, Jesus encouraged tithing only a short time later in Matt 23:23.

Comment: Respectfully, I would suggest that Jesus told the Pharisees that their tithing practices were at fault.

Comment: Matt 23:23 says (emphasis mine) "You give a tenth of your spices--mint, dill and cumin. But you have neglected the more important matters of the law--justice, mercy and faithfulness. You should have practiced the latter, without neglecting the former."  Note the last phrase - I agree that tithing was abused and Jesus wanted to stop the abuse but he does not say to stop.

Comment: When Jesus stopped the exchange of money and sale of animals at the temple He physically made it impossible to continue with the sacrifices and the tithing. He does not say to stop tithing and sacrifices. He physically puts and end to it. For which he was killed. After His death his disciples did not ever institute tithing in their ministries. Paul made a point of supporting himself entirely. In fact it was not until 1285 that the church reconstituted tithing in England. -Tithes in England and Wales
Robert Brown, Jr.

Comment: The money changers were nothing to do with tithing.  I agree that tithing is not enforced in the NT but that is NOT the point of Jesus overthrowing the money changers.  Tithing is NEVER mentioned.

Comment: Actually the money changers were an integral part of tithing. Jews traveling to the temple would have to exchange their various currencies for "temple" coins to pay their tithes. The temple accepted no other currencies.

Comment: For this reason a network of independent money changers evolved. They provided a critical service, especially in Jerusalem, where visiting Jews needed to change their local money into silver coins from Tyre in order to pay their statutory annual half-shekel dues to the Jerusalem Temple    -Surcharge of the Money Changers
by David Hendin

Comment: Yet the rabbis declared that the Tyrian shekels were the only legal currency that was acceptable in the Temple (Hendin 2001:420–29; 2002:46, 47).http://www.biblearchaeology.org/post/2006/11/01/The-Tyrian-Shekel-and-the-Temple-of-Jerusalem.aspx#Article

Comment: I think you are tripping over yourself here.  The temple shekel was certainly a way to extort money at elevated prices for sacrifices but other coins were still acceptable as shown by Mark 12:41-44 and Luke 21:1-4.

Comment: Actually no. The Tyrian shekel was a specific currency as opposed to other country's shekels that were of differing weights and purity. The temple tax was a fixed amount per person - one half of a Tyrian shekel  -  and had to be paid in Tyrian shekels or its derivatives. The smallest Tyrian coin appears to have been a half shekel or a didrachm. A Lepta or Widow's Mite was a bronze coin minted by the Jews. There was 667 Leptas in a Tyrian didrachm but no corresponding Tyrian coin to convert it to so it had to be accepted without exchange. It was too small to worry about.

Comment: Interestingly, the temple tax in Jesus day was for the upkeep of the temple, but shortly afterward, around 70 AD, the temple tax became just another Roman tax.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the temple cleanse was a prophetic fulfillment according to malachi 3:3 and action against the levite priests whom were using the Temple grounds/Fathers House as a means to line there own pockets.

The temple cleanse did not cease tithing nor cease sacrifices or offerings. It is shown in scripture that Paul gave such offerings while the Temple was still standing when he took a vow of purification and paid for others offerings whom too were performing the vow while in Jerusalem. This was done to show the neighboring Jews whom have not of yet accepted Christ, that Paul did not abolish the Law as it was rumored.

But titehing was no longer practiced as there is no evidence of it after the death of Christ in the letters context.but free will offerings are still requested of us without compulsion but by a willing heart to decide in our hearts what we are willing to give in keeping with our wealth. wether it be as charity to blood Jews of the faith, of our own individual generosity to help those inside and outside the Faith and or towards our local assembly. in order to help each other in times of need and support missionary provisions.

At any moment that the Apostles adrressed giving of goods, if titheing was still required of us, then no doubt it would have been mentioned plainly as everything else instructed toward us.

First fruit Tithing of the Lord's portion was specific only to the levite servants of the temple, levetical priests gave no tithes and of the Lord's portion was a tithe giving to the priests. There are other tithes besides the Lord's portion that were specific only of those whom were farmers and shephards to pay such tithes so no other civilians were required to tithe. Such as these tithes were in order to help the sojourners, the poor, and the Levite servants.

We as the Royal Priesthood of believers under our High Priest Christ Jesus of the order of Melchizedek do not pay tithes just as the Levetical priests had no requirement nor obligation to do so. Everyone in Christ as His disciple is a priest. There are no more common people apart from priests as you read in the Old Covenant, under the New Covenant

What we give to each other by free will offerings is giving to Jesus.

As for Malachi 3:10 of the previous poster, has nothing to do with God commanding all citizens of Jerusalem to bring the tithe back to the temple. The ones addressed by God and at fault are the Levite priests whom stole the Lord's portion for themselves, while renting the storeroom meant for the Lord's portion tithe to an gentile to further line there pockets with wealth. It is to them God commanded them to restore the tithes as the Levite temple servants were not receiving there provisions to live off of.

Answer (score 1):

Tithing was ancient Israel's welfare system; and it was not abolished until the Romans came and crushed Israel. However, tithing was never the path to God's heart. Jesus came and showed the right path to God. Jesus said" "tithe, but don't show disrespect for the weightier things like compassion, etc."

> Mat 23:23 (NIV) “Woe to you, teachers of the law and Pharisees, you hypocrites! You give a tenth of your spices—mint, dill and cumin. But you have neglected the more important matters of the law—justice, mercy and faithfulness. You should have practiced the latter, without neglecting the former.

Early Israel was an agrarian society, and it was only primary producers who were required to tithe. A carpenter like Jesus did not have to tithe. It was not like carpenters had to give every tenth chair or table to the levites.

The meat of the sacrifices in the temple went to the priestly clan. It was part of their livelihood. What irritated Jesus was that the merchants and money changers were doing business on holy temple ground. The temple was for worship, not for trading.

> Mat 21:12,13 (NIV) Jesus entered the temple courts and drove out all who were buying and selling there. He overturned the tables of the money changers and the benches of those selling doves. “It is written,” he said to them, “‘My house will be called a house of prayer,’ but you are making it ‘a den of robbers.’”

Comment: Constantthin:  It is true that Levitical priests continued serving at the temple in Jerusalem until it was destroyed in 70 C.E., but Christians from and after 33 C.E. became part of a new spiritual priesthood that was not supported by tithes.​—Ro 6:14; Heb 7:12; 1Pe 2:9.

Comment: According to Malachi the Israelic welfare system was not working very well. The levites did not pass on the tithes to the needy. The reason for this is not clear, but it was either that they did not receive enough to be shared, or that they were outright greedy. In other words, the system was defunct and outdated. And like you said it did not last very much longer. The Christians were never dependent on it. Although Jesus, when the system was still in place, frequently told people to go and show themselves to the priest after he had healed them.

Comment: "The law was nailed to the cross", means that if we crucify our flesh we will in effect stop sinning, and will not have  the need to get atoned. The temple, soon to be gone, served a very small role in Christian history; although in the beginning there were Christian meetings there (Acts 2:46).

Answer (score 1):

```
1   Matthew 23:23: "Woe to you, teachers of the law…You give a tenth…But you have neglected the more important matters-- justice, mercy and faithfulness. You should have practiced the latter, without neglecting the former.
2   Luke 6:38: If you give, you will get! Your gift will return to you in full and overflowing measure, pressed down, shaken together to make room for more, and running over. Whatever measure you use to give-- large or small-- will be used to measure what is given back to you.
3   Luke 6:38: Give, and it will be given to you. A good measure, pressed down, shaken together and running over, will be poured into your lap. For with the measure you use, it will be measured to you."
4   Luke 18:9–14: He also told this parable to some who trusted in themselves that they were righteous, and treated others with contempt: “Two men went up into the temple to pray, one a Pharisee and the other a tax collector. The Pharisee, standing by himself, prayed thus: ‘God, I thank you that I am not like other men, extortioners, unjust, adulterers, or even like this tax collector. I fast twice a week; I give tithes of all that I get.’ But the tax collector, standing far off, would not even lift up his eyes to heaven, but beat his breast, saying, ‘God, be merciful to me, a sinner!’ I tell you, this man went down to his house justified, rather than the other. For everyone who exalts himself will be humbled, but the one who humbles himself will be exalted.
```

There is nothing new under sun.
People are always trying to find a legitimate reason not to tithe or give money.
Why did Jesus even have colletion of offering? He certainly didn’t need it.
It was to show example.
I believe God said a specific amount because he knew most people would give nothing or smallest amount possible when it comes to church or ministry.
Yet we can tip , buy frivolous things and no thoughts about it.

It seems most people who are seeking not to tithe have issues with money one way or either.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Please make sure you take our Tour; see below left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having reviewed the answers to this question I am left with the conclusion that when Jesus cleared the temple of moneychangers he was physically manifesting prophecy and marking the end of the Old Covenant. By this action He not only put an end to animal sacrifices but also ended tithing.

**These are the prophecies:**

Mal 3:1-3 KJV - *1 "Behold, I will send my messenger [ANGELOS], and he shall prepare the way before me: and the Lord, whom ye seek, shall suddenly come to his temple, even the messenger of the covenant, whom ye delight in: behold, he shall come, saith the LORD of hosts. 2 But who may abide the day of his coming? and who shall stand when he appeareth? for he is like a refiner's fire, and like fullers' soap: 3 And he shall sit as a refiner and purifier of silver: and he shall purify the sons of Levi, and purge them as gold and silver, that they may offer unto the LORD an offering in righteousness"*

Jer 31:31-34
*"31 The days are surely coming, says the Lord, when I will make a new covenant with the house of Israel and the house of Judah.32 It will not be like the covenant that I made with their ancestors when I took them by the hand to bring them out of the land of Egypt—a covenant that they broke, though I was their husband, says the Lord. 33 But this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel after those days, says the Lord: I will put my law within them, and I will write it on their hearts; and I will be their God, and they shall be my people. 34 No longer shall they teach one another, or say to each other, “Know the Lord,” for they shall all know me, from the least of them to the greatest, says the Lord; for I will forgive their iniquity, and remember their sin no more."*

**Money Exchange**

The exchange of money and animals for the temple coins necessary to pay the tithe was an integral part of the money changer's operations.

*"In the first century C.E., when pilgrims arrived in Jerusalem, they frequently encountered money changers and merchants around the Jerusalem temple. Merchants sold animals—doves or cattle—for temple sacrifices; it was easier for travelers to buy an animal near the temple than to bring one along.
When Jews traveled to Jerusalem from other lands, they brought money for room, board, and souvenirs. Most importantly, they were required to pay the annual half-shekel tribute to the temple. The currency they had would be of their native land or acquired in trade along their way. Money changers performed a key service when they converted the varieties of local coinage into the required tribute of silver shekels or half-shekels of Tyre (Tosefta Ketubbot 13:20, Exod 30:11-16)."*
http://www.bibleodyssey.org/passages/related-articles/commerce-and-the-temple-in-first-century-jerusalem

**Fulfillment of the Prophecy**

Jesus physically put a stop to the selling of animals and the changing of money that was going on outside the temple. It was more than a random act; it was a symbolic end to the Old Covenant. It turned the Pharisees against Him and initiated their plots against Him.

Mark 11:15-18:
15-17 *"And they come to Jerusalem: and Jesus went into the temple, and began to cast out them that sold and bought in the temple, and overthrew the tables of the moneychangers, and the seats of them that sold doves; And would not suffer that any man should carry any vessel through the temple. And he taught, saying unto them, Is it not written, My house shall be called of all nations the house of prayer? but ye have made it a den of thieves. 18 And the scribes and chief priests heard it, and sought how they might destroy him: for they feared him, because all the people was astonished at his doctrine."*

**Implementation of the New Covenant**

Jesus' actions in clearing the merchants and moneychangers outside the temple physically stopped all trading and exchange. Not only did this put an end to the sacrifice of animals, but it ended the tithing. Neither was possible any longer. Christians have never sought a return to animal sacrifice but we have re-established the tithe, in contradiction to the New Covenant which declares us free from the law and requirements of the Old Covenant.

*“So Christ has truly set us free. Now make sure that you stay free, and don't get tied up again in slavery to the law.”* Galations 5:1

Furthermore, tithing only ever applied to Jews living in Israel. It was never expected from non Jews and did not apply to Jews living abroad.

Additionally, the tithe was to be collected by the Levites. There are currently no Levites and modern day Jews do not tithe because of that fact, and Jews uniformly consider tithing to be a sin under the current conditions. http://www.askelm.com/tithing/thi003.htm

*"It was unlawful for anyone outside of the tribe of Levi to receive the tithe, such as prophets, preachers, kings or evangelists."*
https://www.bereanbiblesociety.org/facts-on-tithing/

*"Neither Peter (not of the tribe of Levi) nor Paul (of the tribe of Benjamin) could receive tithes for the support of their ministries."* evangelists.https://www.bereanbiblesociety.org/facts-on-tithing/

*"Abraham gave tithes to Melchisedec, king of Salem, but this was the spoils of war, not the legalistic tithe of the land which Moses commanded. Also, God did not command the tithe, Abraham chose to give it of his own free will."* (Genesis 14:17-23; Hebrews 7:1-10). https://www.bereanbiblesociety.org/facts-on-tithing/

*"WHO is to give to the Lord’s work? The Christian! He gives systematically, sacrificially, and joyfully. TO WHOM does he give? To Christ! FOR WHAT does he give? For the cause of Christ! NOT to a man or to a church, not for gain, but for the Gospel. "*
https://www.bereanbiblesociety.org/facts-on-tithing/

Answer (score 0):

Your two questions are (along with an inserting of your assertion, too):

1) 'Is this [the overthrew the tables of the moneychangers for Jesus part] symbolic of the end of the Old Covenant and the start of the New Covenant?'

and,

2) 'It marks the end of sacrifices, but does it also mark the end of tithing?'

First of all, the assertion 'It marks the end of sacrifices' is debatable. According the letter to the Hebrews (9:12; 10:1-14), and many other Bible texts, the happening that marked the end of the sacrifices was the offering - for Jesus part - of his perfect body and blood. Before the Messiah sacrificed himself for 'the world' (Joh 3:16) the animal sacrifices performed to the Jerusalem temple were valid (if they were made with right motives, obviously) from God's viewpoint.

Now, returning to your couple of questions, we may say that the answer for both of them is "**No**".

Why?

You say (bold is mine): 'Jesus' actions in clearing the merchants and moneychangers outside the temple **physically stopped all trading and exchange**. Not only did this put an end to the sacrifice of animals, but it ended the tithing. **Neither was possible any longer**.' Also, 'When Jesus stopped the exchange of money and sale of animals at the temple **He physically made it impossible to continue with the sacrifices and the tithing. He does not say to stop tithing and sacrifices. He physically puts and end to it**.'

Now, really, it is 'impossible' that was 'impossible' to perform sacrifices and tithing after the 'overthrowing' action of Jesus, because this was performed by the Messiah **twice**!

The first time was around the Passover of 30 CE (Joh 2:13-15), instead the second time was around three years after, probably on 10 Nisan 33 CE (Mat 21:12-13; Mar 11:15-17; Luk 19:45-46).

At this regard, consider, please these following comments (bold is mine).

Robertson (*Word Pictures in the NT*): "John (Joh 2:14) has a similar incident at the beginning of the ministry of Jesus. **It is not impossible that he should repeat it at the close after three years** with the same abuses in existence again."

Matthew Henry (*Commentary on the Whole Bible*): "What he [Jesus] did (Mat 21:12); He cast out all them that sold and bought; **he had done this once before** (Joh 2:14, Joh 2:15), **but there was occasion to do it again**. Note, Buyers and sellers driven out of the temple, will return and nestle there again, if there be not a continual care and oversight to prevent it, and if the blow be not followed, and often repeated."

The Cambridge Bible
"12–14. **The Second Cleansing of the Temple** (Mar 11:15-18; Luk 19:45-46).
It is clear from the other Synoptists that the Cleansing of the Temple took place on Nisan 10, not on the day of the entry. St Mark says (Mat 11:11) that 'when he had looked round about on all things there, the eventide being come he went back to Bethany'. In point of time 'the cursing of the fig-tree' should precede the 'Cleansing of the Temple.' St Mark adds to this account 'would not suffer that any man should carry any vessel through the temple'. St Matthew alone mentions the healing of the lame and the blind, and omits the incident of 'the widow’s mite', recorded by the other Synoptists. The first 'Cleansing of the Temple', at the commencement of our Lord’s ministry, is recorded Joh 2:13-17." (the same standing you may find in E. W. Bullinger, inside his Companion Bible, on Mar 11:16; also, Jamieson-Fausset-Brown in their Commentary on Mar 11:15-18)

NET Bible (note on Mat 21:12): "John (2:13-16) records **a cleansing of the Temple at the beginning of Jesus ministry**." So, this implies that the 'cleansing' reported by Matthew was the second.

Now, it is clear your claims are without a basis, because it wasn't 'impossible' for the money changers and animal sellers return - after some time from the first Jesus' cleansing - to their shady business. Then, Jesus didn't stop sacrifices and tithing at the time of his two cleansing of the Temple. Like I've said before, was the offering of Jesus to ransom for mankind that this happened, really.

If we have to pick a real symbolic event that could represent the 'divide' between the Old Covenant and the New one, this would be the ripping of the curtain that divided the Holy from the Most Holy (Sancta Sanctorum). In fact, did happen that "instantly, **the curtain of the door of the temple was torn asunder**, from the top to the bottom; and the earth shook; and the rocks rived", et cetera (Mat 21:54, *James Murdock*).

Hebrews 9:12, 23-25 confirms fully this conclusion, comparing Jesus to a High Priest that enter into the Sancta Sanctorum to offer his own blood before IEUE (יהוה), for the sake of all mankind.

Really, instead to think that the purpose of the two Jesus' Temple cleansings was the stopping of the Temple activities like sacrifices and/or tithes, you have to think about the correct conclusion of Mac's Musings when he said that "**Jesus wanted to stop the desecration of the temple courts** being used as a market by money changers and traders charging [...]." (bold is mine)

This is confirmed by a particular mentioned only by Mark (11:16): "and would not suffer that any man should carry any vessel through the temple" (Jubilee Bible).

The Cambridge Bible (cited above) commented (bold is mine): "'**He** [Jesus] **would not allow laden porters and others to desecrate the honour due to His Father’s house** by crossing the Temple courts **as though they were public streets**, '*quasi per plateam*' [according] Bengel.". This particular is peculiar to St Mark."

What an important lesson for us was given from the Messiah! We have to divide our daily activities, not forgetting that the things belonging to God are superior to the profane things. And that we must not mingle these two areas. An example? Taking advantage of our spiritual 'ascendancy' over a religious community to squeeze money out from 'thirsty and hungry' (spiritually speaking) people...

Comment: First, sacrifices were, and still are, valid for the Jews to offer.

Comment: Second, it is doubtful that Jesus did anything for trivial reasons and even more doubtful that the disciples would have recorded events that were not pertinent. Obviously the merchants quickly returned to their businesses but that does not change the fact that Jesus was making a statement here and fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: I've presented enough information to understand what is the truth around this topic. Everyone has to take his own stand. Shalom.

Comment: Third, what do you base your statement that Jesus cleared the temple twice on?